# issue passing a value to a function

Tags: javascript

EDIT: the 'more' link is built from here:

```
document.getElementById("elenco_fiveboard").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 
    "<li>" +
    "Titolo: " + valore_comando + " " + 
    "(<a href='javascript:getInfo("+ valore_comando +");'>" +
    "more" + "</a>)" +
    "</li>");
```

So I have to wrap valore_comando with hyphens but I get error trying to write

```
"(<a href='javascript:getInfo(""+ valore_comando +"");'>" +
```

or

```
"(<a href='javascript:getInfo('"+ valore_comando +"');'>" +
```

Sorry but I am not so strong with JS syntax and I am starting from some code that is not my own.

I have this simple JS function:

```
  getInfo = function(title){ 
    worker.port.postMessage("maggiori_informazioni:" + title);
  }
```

I run it passing to the variable title a value but I always get an error. If title is 'example' then JS try to run

```
getInfo = function(example)
```

and I get the error:

> Reference Error: example is not defined.
>   If title has more than one word: 'first example'
>   then JS will try to run

```
getInfo = function(first example)
```

and I get the error:

> Syntax error: missing ) after argument list (looking for parentesys
>   after 'first').

What am I missing here?? 
This code is part of my first test with webSockets. If you want to see the full code you can open this [index page](http://oclock.dyndns.org/websocket/index.html) and put a value on the first alert you see. That value is the title that you will see on the [dashboard page](http://oclock.dyndns.org/websocket/dashboard.html).
The error can be reproduced trying to hit 'More' after each defined title in dashboard. 
Sorry for italian in the site but it's a user requirement.

Comment: `getInfo("this is a title");`

Comment: What am I missing here?? -- quotation marks around your literal strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to escape some quotation marks.

```
"(<a href=\"javascript:getInfo('"+ valore_comando +"');\">" +
```

The `\` character before the quotation marks for the `href` attribute tells the JavaScript parser that they're part of the string instead of the beginning or end of a string.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It was the missing combination I haven't tried.

Answer (score 2):

`getInfo` having reference to your function. So you can call this by:

```
getInfo(value);
```

> Use quotes if you are passing string value and if you are passing
>   integer value you can simply pass.

For instance:

```
getInfo("Message Title"); //string
getInfo(3); // Integer
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wtp1zh9s/)

---

You can also call like this:

```
getInfo = function(title){ 
    alert("maggiori_informazioni:" + title);
  }("String");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wtp1zh9s/1/)

**Updates:**

You can use this:

```
"(<a href='"+getInfo(valore_comando)+";'>" +
```

Answer (score 1):

1. the function has been assigned to `getInfo` so please call `getInfo()`
2. string should be enclosed with `''`

So the code should be

```
getInfo('example')
```

Comment: This answer gets to the actual point. getInfo is assigned to a function. So call it, don't reassign it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that example is not defined. If you wanted to call the function with example as input it needs either single quotes or double quotes around it. `"example"` or `'example'`.

```
getInfo("example"); // Works as intended
```

Another option is to create a variable containing the string, and pass that to the function.

```
var myVariable = "example";
getInfo(myVariable); // Still works, myVariable is a string with value "example"
```